# remove carriage return from vars in an array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, overwrite, carriage-return

From two different grep commands I have two arrays...

```
list1=( $(grep "something" * | awk -F : '{print $3}') )
list2=( $(grep "something else" * | awk -F : '{print $3}') )
```

Now if I echo this variables they overwrite each other - and I suspect this is because of a carriage-return in the variables...

```
for((i=0;i<${#list1[*]};i++))
do 
    echo "${list1[$i]}' with ${list2[$i]}"
done
```

What I want

```
VariableOne with V2
```

What I get

```
with V2eOne
```

How can I remove that (suspected) carriage return from my arrays? Or may there be an other cause for my problem

Comment: Although it would be better to remove the carriage returns from the files that you `grep` from.

Comment: The files I grep from are not to be changed... I need them as they are

Comment: The linked question would tell you how to remove the CR from the variables.

Comment: Great!  The suggestion for removing the CRs from the input files was intended to complement the one in the linked answer.  Anyways, good that things are working for you.